# Cassandra stop working on AWS (ubuntu server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, bigdata

I have configure cassandra-cluster locally and it works fine, following the same steps I configure cassandra-cluster on AWS on a ubuntu-server instance.

It works fine, but if I stop cassandra service from one node:

```
sudo service cassandra stop
```

And then I start it, this node never connect to the cluster again.
And it fails throwing the next error:

```
* could not access pidfile for Cassandra
```

My cassandra version is 3.7, so if I access to /etc/init.d/cassandra, so the cmd_patt is the next: 
**CMD_PATT="Dcassandra-pidfile=.*cassandra.pid"**

Cassandra version: 3.7

Host: ubuntu server 14.04 (AWS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop cassandra service:

```
sudo service cassandra stop
```

Remove the default dataset:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*
```

Start cassandra service:

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `/var/run/cassandra` folder hence it has wrong permissions:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/run/cassandra
```

Or you can fix permissions manually:

```
sudo chmod 750 /var/run/cassandra
```

Then start Cassandra as service:

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

---

### Some explanations

Instructions of file permissions you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

- It is safe to delete that folder because it recreates with right permissions and content. But do not delete it once it works correct. It may result in loss of data or incorrect behavior.
- `chmod 750` decrypts as rwxr-x--- permissions. It allows read-write-execute to the user, read-execute to the group and nothing to others. For Cassandra, it is enough to set permissions so.

Comment: I have try but it throws the same error.., The strange thing is that locally it works fine, but when I try to execute on AWS it doesn't work.

Comment: Go to sudo vim /etc/init.d/cassandra; and for CMD_PATT replace it with this CMD_PATT="cassandra"

Comment: I have edited the question, can you see if you have any idea of the problem?